# What does point mean in QMenu::actionAt(const QPoint& pt)?

Tags: qt

I am new to Qt. What does point mean in QMenu::actionAt(const QPoint& pt)? Is it a physical position in the screen with what unit (such as pixels)? Or a relative integer index? Or some other meaning? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's XY position, in pixels, relative to the top-left corner of the menu.

Comment: Thanks. So I think the QMenu::actionAt method will be not very useful since it is not easy to get a point position.

Comment: It depends on what you're doing. You can always get the cursor position with `QCursor::pos()`, and most input events give you a location as well.